# Firebase Remote Config: The provided JSON file is not formatted like a Remote Config

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase's [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) service. I am trying to upload a "config from JSON file" as their options suggest, but am shown this error:

[image]

Yet, I'm not sure why my JSON is invalid. Here is the file (`remote_config.json`):

```json
{
    "messages": {
        "welcome_message": "Welcome",
        "other_message": "Hello, there!"
    },
    "app_features": {
        "feature_one_enabled": false,
        "feature_two_enabled": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON looks quite different than the example in the documentaton on [remote config templates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/templates).

To ensure you use the correct format, I recommend creating the template in the Firebase console, [downloading it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/templates#download_current_template) through the API, and then modifying the downloaded template.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't know it wasn't just pure JSON. Thanks!